# How to make tomcat 7 starts (with my application) automatically when system starts

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

1. I have created a desktop JSP application and I have deployed it in tomcat7. I use netbeans to startup tomcat by clicking the tomcat Location `apache-tomcat-7.0.42\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\startup.bat` the black screen file comes and then goes so what can I do to make the startup run.
2. How can I make the tomcat server startup automatically when the system starts as I am delivering this software to a non technical client. So he will face complications to take a lengthy procedure.

Comment: If your're on windows just install tomcat as a service as set it up to start on windows startup. download for that the [windows installer](http://funnyshare.org/mirrors/apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.42/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.42.exe) not the zip version from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi)

Comment: Thanks This was help full. 

All i did is Downloaded Tomcat as service installed and changed the service setting from control panel -> Automatic. And it works fine automatically .